# developing your own RESTful API

Tags: api, rest

in developing your own RESTful API. does it necessarilly needed to use the four different http methods? GET POST PUT & DELETE?

i was checking the [Twitter REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) and saw that they are just using the common methods (GET & POST)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

Long Answer:
REST is not specific to any one protocol, instead it is a style of programming. This is helpful to keep in mind because a RESTful endpoint should be thought of as having specific goals. Your job is to expose the web service in the most RESTful way possible. 
When you're making a RESTful API you are not required to use any specific HTTP methods. Instead, REST can be embodied in this guiding principal: That you must expose individually identifiable resources; these resources must be manipulable in their exposed form. Oh and use self descriptive messages.

I'm sure this is a leaky explanation. Try to see, though, that REST becomes much more clear when you have the key idea in mind. RESTful practices expose resources in a way that allows us work with state in a sane manner. The technical details of how to implement a RESTful API can be learned by reading this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer
After that, read something specific to your language. Fast track: find some RESTful API written in your language and clone it/play with it.

Comment: so this explains why they call it an 'Architectural Style'. it doesnt any specific protocol or standard.

Answer (score 1):

You should use whatever HTTP methods are appropriate for the operations you expose.

For example, you should accept HTTP DELETE requests only for operations that delete things.

If your API does not allow callers to delete things (eg, a traffic or weather API), you should not accept the DELETE verb.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you are going to support those logical operations:

GET - fetch a resource

PUT - update (or create) a resource

DELETE - delete a resource

POST - several uses: create a new resource in a collection, perform some operation that will alter a resource in some one (as opposed to PUTting an entirely new version of a resource)

Most APIs will want to to provide those operations, and will use all those methods. And don't forget HEAD - fetch information about a resource (but not the resource itself).